# Show this sequence is equicontinuous

Tags: analysis

I'm stuck on an analysis problem to which I've reduced to the following, so some assumptions may be superfluous.

Let $\{ f_n(x) \} \subset C(X,\mathbb{R}^{\geq0})$ (i.e. $f_n$ is continuous and nonnegative)  where $X$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Suppose further that for all $n,x$, $f_{n+1}(x) \leq f_n(x)$ and that $f_n$ converges pointwise to the continuous function $f$.

Show that the sequence $f_n$ is equicontinuous.

Any help on this problem is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

By Dini's theorem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini's_theorem, the convergence is uniform.

The sequence is actually uniformly equicontinuous.

Take $\epsilon>0$.

There exists $N$ such that $\sup_X|f_n-f|\leq \epsilon/3$ for all $n\geq N$.

Now $f$ is uniformly continuous on the compact $X$, so there exists $\delta_0>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq \epsilon/3 $ for all $|x-y|\leq \delta_0$.

For all $n\geq N$ and for $|x-y|\leq \delta_0$, we thus have, by triangular inequality
$$
|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|\leq |f_n(x)-f(x)|+|f(x)-f(y)|+|f(y)-f_n(y)|
$$
$$
\leq 2\sup_X|f_n-f|+|f(x)-f(y)| \leq 3\frac{\epsilon}{3}=\epsilon.
$$

Finally, the functions $f_1,\ldots,f_{N-1}$ are all uniformly continuous and in finite number, so we can clearly find $\delta_1>0$ such that $|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|\leq \epsilon$ for all $|x-y|\leq \delta_1$ and all $n=1,\ldots,N-1$.

I remains to take $\delta=\min\{\delta_0,\delta_1\}$ to get $|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|\leq \epsilon$ for all $|x-y|\leq \delta$ and all $n$.

So the functions $(f_n)$ are uniformly equicontinuous.

Comment: Thank you, using Dini's theorem was clever.

One minor note, continuity of $f$ is required: just consider $\{x^n\}$ for $x\in [0,1]$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @student Ah, yes, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Since that $f$ is a continuous function, for $\varepsilon>0$ and $x\in X$ exist $\delta>0$ such that
$$|f(y)-f(x)|<\varepsilon, \ \ \ \mbox{if} \ \ \ |y-x|<\delta.$$
Since that the sequence $(f_n)_n$ converge pointwise,
$$|f_n(x)-f(x)|\longrightarrow0, \ \ \ \ |f_n(y)-f(y)|\longrightarrow0,$$
for $n$ sufficiently huge. Using the monotonicity of the sequence, we obtain
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
|f_1(x)-f_1(y)| & \leq & |f_1(x)-f(x)|+|f_1(y)-f(y)|+|f(y)-f(x)|\\
                & \leq & |f_n(x)-f(x)|+|f_n(y)-f(y)|+|f(y)-f(x)|\longrightarrow0,
\end{array}
$$
when $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is sufficiently huge and $|y-x|<\delta$. This same argument can be used for $f_2, f_3,...,f_n...$. Then, 
$$|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|<\varepsilon, \ \ \ \ \mbox{if} \ \ \ |y-x|<\delta,$$
for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, like desired.

Comment: I think you have a mistake in this step:
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
|f_1(x)-f_1(y)| & \leq & |f_1(x)-f(x)|+|f_1(y)-f(y)|+|f(y)-f(x)|\\
                & \leq & |f_n(x)-f(x)|+|f_n(y)-f(y)|+|f(y)-f(x)|\longrightarrow0,
\end{array}
$$

$f_n(x)$ is decreasing in n, so $|f_1(x)-f(x)| \geq |f_n(x)-f(x)|$

$$ $$
I don't think it matters, but for the problem I'm working on, it suffices to show that the sequence is eventually equicontinuous, i.e. for a given $\epsilon>0$, the $\delta>0$ required for continuity need only be true for the family $\{f_n : n\geq N\}$ for some large $N$.

Answer (score 0):

By continuity of f ; for every $\varepsilon > 0$ (given $x\in $X$)$  , there exist $\Delta>0$ such that
$$|f(y)-f(x)|<\varepsilon/3 \ \ \ \mbox{if}  \ \ \ |y-x|<\Delta.$$
Since  the sequence $(f_n)$ converges pointwise,

$|f_N(x)-f(x)|<\varepsilon/3$     and     $|f_N(y)-f(y)|<\varepsilon/3$
 for  sufficiently large $N$.

And for $n\geq$ $N  $ , we have 
$|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|\leq \ $$|f_N(x)-f(x)|$+$|f_N(y)-f(y)|$+$|f(y)-f(x)|$ $<\epsilon$

Then just take $\delta= min $$\{\delta_1,\delta_2,..,\delta_N,\Delta\}$ where $\delta_i$ satisfies $:|f_i(x)-f_i(y)| <  \varepsilon $ if  $|x-y|<\delta_i                $  .

So , by definition , $f_n$ is equicontinuous.

Comment: I think this step is the same as José Carlos' which doesn't follow since the inequality in the monotonicity assumption is in the opposite direction.
$$|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|\leq |f_N(x)-f(x)|+|f_N(y)-f(y)|+|f(y)-f(x)| <\epsilon$$

Comment: You are correct in the inequality. However, something else doesn't set right with me.

When you choose $N$, you choose it depending on $x$ and $y$. This in turn makes $\delta$ depend on $x,y$, and so equicontinuity doesn't follow.

Comment: Yes, I agree it is essentially the same as Julien's if you appeal to dini's theorem and use uniform convergence to find an $N$ independent of $x$ and $y$ (instead of pointwise convergence).

Comment: you don't need to show uniform convergence for equicontinuity.With 2 points (x and y)  , you don't need it..